# What is the difference between Event Bus and Event Stream in AKKA?

Tags: akka

What is the difference between Event Bus and Event Stream in AKKA? I read the documentation but I am still confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term "bus" or "event bus" is a generic computer science term that pre-dates akka.  From [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_(computing)):

> In computer architecture, a bus (a contraction of the Latin
>   omnibus) is a communication system that transfers data between
>   components inside a computer, or between computers.

The [EventStream](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4/scala/event-bus.html#Event_Stream) is the primary instantiation of an event bus in akka.  From the documentation:

> The event stream is the main event bus of each actor system: it is
>   used for carrying log messages and Dead Letters and may be used by the
>   user code for other purposes as well.

The documentation is just saying "you don't have to create a bus on your own, we've created one for you and you can access it with [ActorSystem#eventStream](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.4.11/index.html#akka.actor.ActorSystem@eventStream:akka.event.EventStream)".

To use an analogy: lookup table is to HashMap as event bus is to EventStream.